# Why Use a Spread Operator Followed by an Iterable Instead of Just the Iterable Itself When Instantiating a Collection in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, iterable

For example with the following List:

```
var originalList = ['follow', 'spread', 'operators.'];
```

When referencing it to make another List, why use the spread operator:

```
var spreadList = ['See? I', ...originalList]
```

Instead of without the spread operator:

```
var lonelyList = ['Actually I dont', originalList]
```

When the results for spreadList and lonelyList respectively are:

```
[See? I, follow, spread, operators.]
[Actually I dont, follow, spread, operators.]
```

Comment: My results are not the same as yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In this statement:**

```
var spreadList = ['See? I', ...originalList]
```

With the spread operator you're inserting each individual `String` element from `originalList` as it's own element into `spreadList`. The end result being a:

`<String>['See? I', 'follow', 'spread', 'operators']`

**But in this statement:**

```
var lonelyList = ['Actually I dont', originalList]
```

You're inserting the entire List as the second element. The end result being a:

`<dynamic>['Actually I dont', ['follow', 'spread', 'operators']]`

You probably didn't notice the second set of square brackets on the output

Comment: Castillo answer is correct, i think D'errah Richardson question result [Actually I dont, follow, spread, operators.]  is not correct, it should be like ['Actually I dont', ['follow', 'spread', 'operators']]

Comment: Yes, I should've copy pasted. I see the difference now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below is my code:

```
var originalList = ['follow', 'spread', 'operators.'];
var spreadList = ['See? I', ...originalList];
var lonelyList = ['Actually I dont', originalList];
print(spreadList);
print(lonelyList);
```

Here is my result:

```
I/flutter (26526): [See? I, follow, spread, operators.]
I/flutter (26526): [Actually I dont, [follow, spread, operators.]]
```

You can see that when using `...originalList` it removes the square brackets. This means that when using `...originalList` it adds multiple strings, but using `originalList` adds a list.